# How to run a unit test with config file that shouldn't be in repo

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

In my local environment, I have the following test case:

```
def setUp(self) -> None:

    config_path = '../config.json'
    self.config = load_json(config_path)

def test_operate(self):
    result = operate(self.config) # Which returns a simple dict by using the info in config
    default_values = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

    self.assertDictEqual(result, default_values)
```

In the local, I have that `config.json` file so tests are working fine. However, since this file contains some secrets I cannot push it to the repo. Thus, my code cannot pass the tests step in actions.

And if I remove the test function, I lose the min. coverage value.

How can I run this test without the config file? Can mocking help me and how?

Comment: Have you considered using repository secrets ?

Comment: Yes, but this is not possible at the moment because of the company policy.

Comment: If `operate` receives a dictionary, why not create a dummy dictionary object in the `setUp` (without loading the config file)?

Comment: `operate` sends some request to an API using credentials in `config.json` file. When I use a dummy dictionary - or a config file with dummy credentials - I am unable to get the data from `operate`